# Evaluate string (string to []string)

Tags: go

I have a string in Go (`'["a","b","50"]'`) which I need to convert into a `[]string` type. 
To me, that is basically evaluating the string, but I have no idea how to do this in Go (I come from Python). I did search the `strconv` package documentation, but did not really find anything that worked.

Comment: Note that `eval` is a very dangerous thing in general.  The Python version has been revised a lot over time and in Python3 you can restrict it to reduce this danger, but if you don't carefully vet *input* and just blindly feed it to some execution engine, you get https://xkcd.com/327/  If your string is JSON, as it seems to be, see Alexey Soshin's answer.

Comment: golang is compiled, so an _"eval"_ doesn't really exist. The string can be marshalled/encoded, and thus unmarshalled/decoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `json` package for that, as your string is clearly a JSON array:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := `["a","b","50"]`
    slice := []string{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &slice)

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", slice)
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to use `strings.Split(str, ",")`, but then you'll have to strip those `[]` and `""`